# Selective module compiling in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

is there a way to selectively compile modules per flavor?

I am trying to reduce build time in development by not compile various modules when running `debug` flavor.

in Eclipse, I would not put them in the `libs` folder and instead put them in the `addon-libs` and compile them only when exporting (via a gradle  build script) and in the code have something like this:

```
try {
   if(Class.forName(clazz) {
      doStuffForLib();
   }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
   // DO NOTHING
}
```

my question is, can I do something similar in my build.gradle now and reduce build time some more?

i.e., I would write something like this

```
buildTypes {
   debug{
   }

   release {
      compile 'some.module:version:1.+'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around I found [this JIRA ticket](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-784) that fixed my issue.

You can supply compiles per version and use the `provided` dependency task for the others while maintaining the code provided for avoiding use of modules that weren't compiled when they aren't present as such

```
public boolean isClassFound(String clazz) {
    try {
        return Class.forName(clazz);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false
}
```

And in the `build.gradle` add:

```
dependencies {
    provided 'some.module:version:1.+'
    releaseCompile 'some.module:version:1.+'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with flavors or buildTypes using.

```
dependencies {
    flavor1Compile xxx
    debugCompile xxxx
}
```

Comment: will this pass lint when running debug?

Comment: What do you mean with "pass lint"?

Comment: I mean, will the editor show an error and fail to run?
if I wouldn't have added the jars in Eclipse to the `addon-libs` the code wouldn't compile, I'm afraid that doing this will cause all debug builds to not compile

Comment: Of course you can't use in debug the classses that you are only including in the release version. You have to provide different implementation between debug and release in this case

Comment: that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, in Eclipse, I would have the classes link in dev but not when compiling in ANT, however now, I cannot run this since the code won't compile because the classes are not linked